# Back camera vs. Back dual camera on iPhone X

Tags: iphone, camera

When searching through my Photos library, I found four different descriptions of the back camera of the iPhone X:

- iPhone X back camera 4mm f/1.8
- iPhone X back camera 6mm f/2.4
- iPhone X back dual camera 4mm f/1.8
- iPhone X back dual camera 6mm f/2.4

4mm and f/1.8 vs. 6mm f/2.4 is about the telephoto lens, but why are some of my photos "back camera" and some (the majority) "back dual camera"?

Some of the non-"dual" photos can be explained by me maybe using an alternative camera app, but not (I think) all of them.